# Black holes attracting each other

Tags: gravity, black-holes, big-bang

I was watching the tv series called, through the wormhole, and they mentioned a theory about multiple universes that are separated by a very small distance, like parallel membranes. They mentioned that there is also a theory that says that black holes are in fact connections between these 2 universes and that the matter travels between them (goes into a black hole in this universe, goes out from a white hole on the other) since the gravity is so strong it manages to pull the other universe's membrane close enough for stuff to travel between them. Also I remember another episode mentioned that the big bang could in fact be these two universe membranes colliding into each other.

So this got me thinking, wouldn't many black holes attract each other and become a super gigantic point of matter that is so strong that it pulls the other universe strongly enough to touch it in which makes the universe with the black hole finally blow up and expel the matter accumulated there as if it was the big bang? This kind of effect would also account for the way the universe expands (if you visualize it as a membrane that has been pulled inwards, when released it grows uniformly in every direction similar to a drop of water creating ripples.

But then i was told black holes would not attract each other because they are drifting away from each other, the speed at which both of them separate from each other is faster than the speed of light  which is said to be the speed the gravity force travels at. But wouldn't they still attract other black holes that are not as fast? (even if they are just slowly moving towards each other) and thus decelerating the speed they get away from each other. And these black holes could be affecting other black holes close to each other, and at the end everything is really affecting something else because regardless of the speed they are within something's gravitational pull which in turn will lead to an implosion generating a super massive black hole (like i described before) making another big bang?

Comment: You get this upvote as a protest against the robo-closers of the site (see http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5868/why-were-well-known-valid-solutions-of-the-gr-off-topic-or-non-mainstream if you like).

Comment: The way I see the question, it is not about new theories. I think the asker does not understand how gravity works, and asks for clarification. That is quite legitimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a distance, black holes are no different from any other matter. Their gravitational attraction is the same as that of any other body with the same mass.

If you were to suddenly convert a star into a black hole of the same mass, any planets around that star will keep moving in exactly the same orbits as before. Observers on the planets would not notice any difference - except for the trivial fact that their sun had just disappeared.

Black holes behave according to the laws of gravity: they will be deflected from their path by gravitational attraction, and they can even orbit each other. The attraction they have on each other depends on their mass and their distance. They do not have to go "faster than light" to keep their separation.

Comment: That makes sense, i had the impression their gravitational pull was stronger. But is there a maximum distance in where gravity no longer affects objects? if there isn't then why isn't everything in the universe attracting each other ultimately leading into things becoming one big clump of stuff?

Comment: Gravity works infinitely far away. However, it weakens with the square of the distance (if you're 2 times further, gravity is 4 times weaker). Also, gravity only works in a straight line between the bodies. If one (or both) moves sideways, that sideways movement is not affected. That is how planets orbit the sun: they want to keep moving in a straight line, but the sun pulls them so their path is bent into an ellipse around the sun.